# How to invoke a Java based webscript from inside a Java based WS

Tags: alfresco

Within a Alfresco(4.1) Java based Webscript, I need to invoke another Alfresco Java based Webscript(/alfresco/service/customservice?abc...).

I don't prefer making a Apache HttpClient call as its a bad practice for many obvious reasons . I did come across remote.connect approach but I guess its for calling a JS based WS.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Somu

Answer (score 3):

It would indeed be bad practice to make a call over the network when you are already in process. Extract the code you want to reuse. Make it independent of the network (webscripts). Make it a spring managed bean you inject in your Java code. In case you need to call it from JS, derive the (Spring bean) from `baseJavaScriptExtension`.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. The java based webscript that I want to invoke is inside a jar(that came with a plugin/addon). I dont have the source but will try for it. Given the jar file, do you have any suggestions on invoking/using the webscript?

Comment: Only (very ugly) hacks if you really have to call the webscript. Even if you don't have the source, I would not expect a lot of logic heavy in the webscript. Check whether there are other beans which you can (re-)use instead.